# Why there is an empty space below cases?

Tags: cases, empheq

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\begin{rcases}
    a=b \\
    c=d
\end{rcases} 
    \Rightarrow a-c=b-d \\
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated but `article` class does not have a `9pt` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You are forcing an empty line, replace

```
   \Rightarrow a-c=b-d \\
```

by

```
    \Rightarrow a-c=b-d
```